# How escape sequence works in python os.path.exists()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working in a Ubuntu system. How does os.path.exists() resolve the below path to True.

```
import os

apath = '/home/.//<user>/'
actual_path = '/home/<user>/'

os.path.exists(apath) #returns True
os.path.exists(actual_path) #returns True
```

I know its a basic question, but does Python consider './' as escape sequence here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a Python issue, you are using a valid path on any POSIX system.

- `.` is the *current directory*. `/existing/directory/` and `/existing/directory/.` are one and the same path. Compare this to `..`, a reference to the parent directory.
- `//` is seen as a single `/` separator.

So `/home/.//<user>/` is the same as `/home/./<user>/` is the same as `/home/<user>/`. In Python or in your shell.

If you need to compare paths, you'd want to *normalise* the path, with [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath):

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.normpath('/home/.//<user>/')
'/home/<user>'
```

For cross-platform applications, you can use the [`os.curdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.curdir) variable if you need the correct string for the 'current directory' for the current platform.

Comment: I accepted you answer, but, I tried to understand your logic in a Windows system. As WINDOWS is not a POSIX env.

`patha = 'D:\\'`
`pathb = '\\important\\'`
`checkPath = os.path.join(patha, './' + pathb)  # 'D:\\./\\important\\'`

Comment: @PikluDey: Windows uses the same value for `os.curdir`, but the default path separator is the backslash, see `os.sep`. `/` is acceptable as an alternative, and is available as `os.altsep`. `os.path.normpath(checkPath)` will produce `'D:\\important'`.